# Variance of 2 Protocols: Sampling Coloured Balls with Dots

Tags: probability, variance, estimation

Suppose, we have an urn where each ball has one of $M$ colours and some balls have a dot. We would like to estimate the proportion $p$ of balls that have a dot. We have two experimental protocols:

1. We sample $n$ balls, count $X=Bin(n,p)$ balls that have a dot, and compute $\hat p=X/n$.
2. Suppose, we know that all balls of colour $i:1\le i\le N$ have a dot, and all balls of colour $j:N<j\le M$ have no dot. Hence, we could estimate for each colour $i:1\le i\le N$, the proportion $p_i$ of balls with colour $i$ that have a dot and compute $\hat p'$ as their unweighted sum, $\hat p'=\sum_{i=1}^N \hat p_i$. Specifically, we first *sequentially* iterate over all colours, and for colour $i$, we sample $n$ balls, count $X_i=Bin(n,p_i)$ balls that have the current colour $i$, and compute $\hat p_i=X_i/n$. Hence, $\hat p'=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i/n$.

Our first observation is, of course, that the second protocol is very inefficient and requires $N-1$ times more samples. Our second observation is that $n\hat p$ is binomial distribution while $n\hat p'$ is a special case of a Poisson binomial distribution.

I will also claim that the variance of $\hat p$ is strictly smaller than the variance of $\hat p'$, i.e., $Var(\hat p)<Var(\hat p')$.

\begin{align}
Var(X')&=\sum_{i=1}^NVar(X_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j:j>i}^N Cov(X_i,X_j)\\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^Np_i(1-p_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j:j>i}^N Cov(X_i,X_j)\label{eqn:this}\\
Var(X) &= np(1-p)\\
&=n\left(\sum_{i=1}^Np_i\right)\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^Np_i\right)\\
    &=\frac{n}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^Np_i\right)\left(N-\sum_{i=1}^NNp_i\right)\\
    &=\frac{n}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^Np_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N(1-Np_i)\right)\\
    &\le n\sum_{i=1}^Np_i(1-Np_i) \quad\text{ by Chebychev}\\
    &< n\sum_{i=1}^Np_i(1-p_i)\\
    &\le Var(X')
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}
Var(\hat p) < Var(\hat p')
\end{align}

Now, here comes the insight: **Both protocols estimate the same quantity, but the second protocol provides an estimate with larger variance even though substantially more samples are taken.**

Are my assumptions correct? Are there any holes in my proof? Can someone explain intuitively, why this works?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you clarify the second protocol:  "only balls of colour $i$ have a dot" sounds like no other balls have dots, i.e. $p_i>0$ and $p_j=0$ for all $i=j$, but based on the remainder it sounds like other colours can have dots. Furthermore, do you assume the proportions of colours in the population are known?

Comment: I have clarified that there are $M$ colours in total and that all balls of colour $i:1\le i\le N$ have a dot while all balls of colour $j:N<j\le M$ have no dot.

Comment: If $N=2$, $n=1$, $X_1=1,~X_2=1$,  (We draw one red ball, it has a dot, we draw one blue ball, it has a dot), is $\hat{p}'$  intended to be $(X_1+X_2)/n = (1 + 1)/1 = 2$?

Comment: Yes. The estimate $\hat p'=\sum X_i/n$ of $p=E[\hat p] = E[\sum \hat p_i] = \sum E[\hat p_i] = \sum p_i$ can have values larger than 1 -- unlike $\hat p=X/n$. I guess this is also the intuition I was seeking why $\hat p$ can have a lower variance than $\hat p'$.

Comment: Ah! I had misread th esecond protocol after all! My mistake, deleted the previous comments